# Which format should the "fun" in scipy.optimize.minimize() have?

Tags: python, scipy

I would like to use the `scipy.optimize.minimize()` function, but I have a small problem : in [the official documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize), it is said that the function take as argument an "objective function", without further precision.

So i wanted to know a few things : let's suppose here that the function I want to optimize is `f(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,...,x_n,y_n)`, n not constant.

1) Is it possible to put other arguments in the function ? for example, `f(stuff,x1,...)` ?

2) As n is not constant, i would rather use a list (something like that :`f([x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,...,x_n,y_n]`). Will scipy understand this ?

Thank you in advance for answers !

Comment: Check that title - I think you meant `scipy.optimize`, not `spicy.optimize`. :)

Comment: @numbermaniac in situations like that just edit the post and it will go into the review queue.

Comment: You're right... :D !

Comment: `f(x, *args)`.  `x` is a 1d array whose size is determined by initial value parameter.  `args` is provided by the `args` parameter, a tuple.

Comment: What does it mean that *`n` is not constant*? If the number of parameters is supposed to change during the optimization you are out of luck (`minimize` won't do that) and you should consider reformulating the problem. If you just want a variable number of parameters, see the comment above.

Comment: I meant that n was a global parameter which could vary, not during the optimization process, but between two optimizations ^^. That's why I wanted a variable number of parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've got some elements of answers :

As hjpaul said, I used an array to solve my problem, and it works ! One should note that if you give him a n-dimensional array, the function will transform it automatically in 1d-array (what blocked me at a moment).

The syntax `sp.optimize.minimize(fun,array,other_args_tuple)` is probably the best, but using global variable works too.

Thank you everyone (and especially hpaulj) for your answers. I didn't read accurately enough the documentation, that'll teach me ^^